# Multiplying string with a double

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with my code. So I know I can't multiply what I have by the string, but I don't really know of any other way to do this. The length comes from an external file show below:

FH4536.266

Here is the part of my code with the issue:

```
String length = line.substring(4);
           String age = line.substring(2,4);
           double h = 0;
           String space = " ";

           if(gender == 'M')
           {
               switch(bone)
               {
                   case 'F':
                   h = 69.089 + (2.238 * length);
                   break;
```

I want to be able to multiply the length, but I don't know how I can do this. Could someone please explain on how I can do this? All the feedback/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has been answered many times before, in short `double.parseDouble(length);`

Comment: Not connected to your problem, but is `gender` of type `String` or `char`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse string to double:

```
double length = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the length to a numeric type (double) using `double lenDbl = Double.parseDouble(length);` (with appropriate exception handling)

`Double.valueOf()` should also work - valueof returns a `Double` class instance. parseDouble returns a `double` primitive type.